# Slider in repeat control and manipulation of text via jOuery

Tags: jquery, xpages

I have a slider with a range selector. Now I display the values in a computed field.
The script for that is:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $(".sliderDsp").slider({
    tooltip_position:'top'
 });        
 $(".sliderDsp").on('slide', function(slideEvt) {
    var sliderDspValStr = "Von " + slideEvt.value[0] + " bis " + slideEvt.value[1];
    $(".sliderDspVal").text(sliderDspValStr);
 });
});
```

I use a class for the manipultion of the text. In a repeate control now all text manipulate. Correct, that's clear.
Now I use the ID but the function can find it. I use the x$ function but the function can find it.

```
x$(sliderID).text(sliderDspValStr);
```

What is the fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you calculating the ID in your CSJS? `"#{id:myComponent}"` cannot access the client-side ID of a component of a repeat if it's placed outside the repeat.

Client-side IDs within a repeat control are calculated dynamically, part of which includes the row index. Look in Firebug and you'll see this. Outside the repeat row, the component tree has no concept of how many rows are displayed or which row you want.

For any CSJS manipulation of a repeat control, use classes. To make a class unique for a specific row, compute it using `"myClass#{idex}"` where `idex` corresponds to the variable name you've assigned to the `indexVar` property of the repeat.

Comment: One more question. In the repeat control is a custom control. In the custom control is the computed text and the scriptblock. How can I tell the script the indexVar? The indexVar can change because I use this on other places.

Comment: Custom controls are just inserted into the component tree at the relevant point when the parent XPage is opened. So for the custom control, as long as the variable name is the same in all repeats it's inserted into, the variable value will be found. Think of it like copying and pasting the custom control's contents into every XPage it's used in, without any changes. The topics are already included in the content for my session at IBM Connect next month.

Comment: And if the variable is not the same? We have many repeat control with other variables.

Comment: You may be able to pass down via compositeData, but I'm not sure. Wherever they are defined, variables are scoped only to descendants of wherever they're placed (e.g. multiple repeats on the same page can have `var="entry"` because "entry" is only available on descendant components / custom controls of each repeat). This is one reason why it's best to scope to Panels rather than XPage / Custom Control. Then the same variable name can be used and will be context-sensitive.

Comment: The problem is that the unique classname must in the jQuery Script in the ScriptBlock. The name of the indexVar is not the same in all repeat controls. The reapeat var cannot be used. CompositeData cannot displayed in a jQuery Script. Or can I put compositeData into a ScriptBlock?

Comment: You can add SSJS into a script block using `#{javascript:....}`. It will be computed server-side and the result put into the text value of the script block, which is passed as CSJS to the browser. That should include compositeData, but I don't think you can use EL in a script block or combine "computed on page load" and "computed dynamically" SSJS int he same script block.